# In what cases can we show that the ground state wavefunction from the variational principle is at all similar to the true wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, atomic-physics, variational-principle

The variational principle gives a ground state that minimises the expected energy from the TISE, while from this we can be sure that we have an upper bound on the ground state energy, it is not always true that the trial wavefunction that satisfies this condition will also be the closest trial wavefunction to the true ground state wavefunciton.

(Wikipedia says the trial wavefunction is not always the closest with

> There is an additional complication in the calculations described. As ε tends toward E0 in minimization calculations, there is no guarantee that the corresponding trial wavefunctions will tend to the actual wavefunction. This has been demonstrated by calculations using a modified harmonic oscillator as a model system, in which an exactly solvable system is approached using the variational method.

In what cases can we be sure that it is the closest?

Comment: By what metric would you call two wavefunctions $\psi$ and $\phi$ close?  The two measures of "distance" which come to mind are $\Vert\psi-\phi\Vert^2$ and $1-|\left<\psi,\phi\right>|^2$ (assuming both are normalized), but which one you choose would be important here.

Comment: How do you know "it is not always true"?

Comment: In general the variational principle gives you the upper ground to the trail ground state (GS). For cases where the GS is the minimum uncertainty state you land up with the exact GS. For example in the case of a SHO, text book examples assume the GS to be a Gaussian (which is a minimum uncertainty state), and you get the exact result.